# what is the best way to create a self-installing, all-included package for distributing a Symfony application?

Tags: php, installation, symfony-1.4

We've developed a Symfony application. We would like to offer it as an online service residing on our servers, but also we think it would be good to be able to provide a one-click-installer for the masses, something capable of:

1. install a webserver (presumably apache), pre-configured for Symfony 1.4, working on a "harmless" port (such as 8888), with php and related modules (ACP, etc)
2. install the DBMS, likely MySQL (but it could be SQLite as well), using another harmless port
3. extract the source of the application
4. building the database and loading the necessary fixtures

it would be nice a cross-platform installer, of course.

what would you suggest? just give up? use a virtual machine? use python?

**update**
It seems another possibility is to use an-all-in-one package such as XAMPP or similar, maybe to be coupled with a phar archive of the application. I'll keep explore.

Comment: I don't think you really want to do that! It's a pain to maintain such a package, isn't it?

Comment: Bundle a version of PHP with the built-in dev-only server and a PHAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual machine. There you create your own environment, specific to your package. So you can control things. It is pretty complex task to create php installer though: lots of nuances with server software on different environments.

Also - it is easier to maintain and to deploy the virtual machine.